# Make a user unique using ip address or device serial number

Tags: php

I managed to allow a user to login with multiple accounts such as google, Facebook and twitter, but this is now causing me problems as Im running competitions were a user can vote, is it possible to make a user or vote unique in my database by using his or her IP address or the device serial number? please do advise if there are other options

Comment: ip addresses never have and never will uniquely identify a user. You also cannot access "device serial number" using merely http.

Comment: All theese services have email. You can, at least, narrow it down checking the email that account is associated. But keep in mind that it is not proof safe as a user can have many emails or services accounts. You can combine info like that user ip with his account (face, twitter, or what so ever)

Comment: thats the problem, the multiple email addresses, so there is no way to make a device unique?

Comment: Nope... No method that you can use is safe proof.

Comment: Let me correct that. You can, otherwise make an applet with a  certificate which will ask to the user permission to work (to have access to his device). On the applet you can write code to get the serial. But then you have another problem, what serial you will get? Because for every device with Operational System you will have to develop especific methods to get the serial. And I'm talking just about devices here. What about computer, which serial you will get? It is too many problem.

Comment: Ok, really can't take that route, can i rely on the IP address for at least an hour?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was out. **No you can't**. Not even for a minute. Imagine a guy with a service provider on his house, he has just to reboot his modem to get a new IP (at least on Brazil it works like that, most of it). In a minute anyone can have many different IPs. Best you can do is relly on email account or create a user account for your site (but it not avoid a person to have many accounts)